# Is the interior of simply closed curve homeomorphic to disk?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am strongly guessing that the interior of any simple closed curve in $R^2$ should be homeomorphic to unit disc $D$. But I cannot prove it.

Is it true?

Then can you shed me some idea for proving this?

(here, the simple closed curve C is homeomorphic to $S^1$ and the interior of this is the bounded component of $R^2-C$ by Jordan Curve Theorem.)

Comment: Yes, it is true. This is the [Jordan–Schoenflies theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Sch%C3%B6nflies_theorem#Original_formulation).

Comment: @ZevChonoles That can totally be an answer.

Comment: Zev, Thanks for letting me know great theorem. You hitted the point!^^ By the way, I am also wondering whether the existence of a homeomorphism $f:R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ such that $f(C)=S^1$ also imply the Jordan curve theorem? I mean the bounded and unbounded components of a simply closed curve $R^2-C$ is once and for all fixed concept by Joran curve theorem. But if we define bounded and unbounded components of $R^2-C$ as the image $f(D)$ and $f(D^c)$, then are they well defined? I mean are they invariant notion regardless the choice of homeomorphism $f$?